# Find nested GridView with Button Click?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I would like to find the nested GridView `gvR` on a button click, so that I can add a row to it.  I will post the GridView markup and then the code for adding the row to the selected nested grid.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnAdd" runat="server" Text="Add Room" 
            onclick="btnAdd_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
        <asp:GridView ID="gvRP" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
            onrowdatabound="gvRP_RowDataBound" 
            onrowediting="gvRP_RowEditing">
        <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Room" ItemStyle-Width="100%">
        <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Room"></asp:Label>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlRoom" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" DataTextField="Name"
            DataValueField="Id" AppendDataBoundItems="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlRoom_SelectedIndexChanged">
            <asp:ListItem Value="-1">Select...</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="ddlRate" Text="Rate" ID="lblRate"></asp:Label><asp:DropDownList
            ID="ddlRate" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true" DataTextField="Name"
            DataValueField="Id">
            <asp:ListItem Value="-1">Select...</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>

        <asp:Label  runat="server" Text="Adults"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtAdults" Text='<%#Bind("Adults") %>' runat="server" Width="25px"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Label  runat="server" Text="Children"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtChildren" Text='<%#Bind("Children") %>' runat="server"  Width="25px"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Check In"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtCheckIn" Text='<%#Bind("CheckIn") %>' runat="server" Width="75px"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Label  runat="server" Text="Check Out"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtCheckOut" Text='<%#Bind("CheckOut") %>' runat="server"  Width="75px"></asp:TextBox>

        <h3>Rates</h3>
        <asp:GridView ID="gvR" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
        <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Rate" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Effective" HeaderText="Effective" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Expire" HeaderText="Expire" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Amount" HeaderText="Amount" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Code" HeaderText="Currency" />
        </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
        </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

Code for adding Rate:

```
protected void AddRate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lstRateDetails = (List<RateDetail>)ViewState["Rates"];

    lstRateDetails.Insert(0, new RateDetail());
    //Have no idea what to do here? I have also tried gvRatePlans.TemplateControl...
    GridView gvR = (GridView)gvRP.FindControl("gvR");
    gvR.DataSource = lstRateDetails;
    gvR.DataBind();

    ViewState["Rates"] = lstRateDetails;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If gvRP is parent grid and gvR is nested grid. As nest grid is contained in each row of container grid so we need to find it in row of parent grid. You can get nested grid contained in first row like this

```
GridView gvR = (GridView)gvRP.Rows[0].FindControl("gvR");
gvR.DataSource = lstRateDetails;
gvR.DataBind();
```

Comment: Are you saying the OP is merely using the wrong names for the controls?

Comment: No, infact I think he has to find nested grid in row of container grid just updated my answer

Comment: OK, this partially works, but I need to add a row to the selected nested GridView, not the first only the first one.  There can be multiple nested GridViews

Comment: I think you have to add row to data source and bind the grid again with data source, You can get as many nested grid by using the same method

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing is using the `NamingContainer` of the LinkButton to find the selected `gvR` GridView.  Here is the code:

```
    LinkButton lnk = (LinkButton)sender;
    lstRateDetails = (List<RateDetail>)ViewState["Rates"];
    lstRoomDetails = (List<RoomDetail>)ViewState["Rooms"];

    lstRateDetails.Insert(0, new RateDetail());
    GridViewRow gvr = (GridViewRow)lnk.NamingContainer;
    int selectedRow = gvr.RowIndex;
    GridView gvR = (GridView)gvRP.Rows[selectedRow].FindControl("gvR");
```